# Create a function that will increment by one when called

Tags: python, count

I am needing a function that will increment by one every time it is called. I have used count but every time I do it resets the count back to the original value plus one count. I have seen lots of code but none of it works. Here is what I have now

I have done lots of looking into loops and iterations

```
def count_row():
    count = 1  
    while count >= 1:
        yield count
        count += 1 
return count
```

Comment: In order for `count` to return +1 in each call it has to "remember" the last value. Or in other words you need some state shared between calls. Does this help?

Comment: Yes that makes perfect sense but I just don't know how to do that.

Comment: What else does this function do besides return an ever-increasing number? You might want to look into the `enumerate` function, which lets you pair an increasing number with a value from an iterator. `enumerate(some_list)` is roughly the same as `zip(range(0, len(some_list)), some_list)`.

Comment: The idea is to use this with xlwings to iterate down excel rows and based on the cell value use a formula to insert data.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `itertools.count`.

```
from itertools import count

counter = count(1)
next(counter) # 1
next(counter) # 2
```

### Stateful function

If you absolutely want a stateful function instead of calling `next`, you can wrap the `count` in a function.

```
def counter(_count=count(1)):
    return next(_count)

counter() # 1
counter() # 2
```

### Class

Alternatively, `itertools.count` being a class, you can inherit from it to extend it's behaviour and make it a callable.

```
class CallableCount(count):
    def __call__(self):
        return next(self)

counter = CallableCount(1)

counter() # 1
counter() # 2
```

Using a class would be my preferred approach since it allows instantiating multiple counters.

Answer (score 3):

You need a closure. Define a function `make_counter` which initializes a local variable, then defines and returns a function that increments that variable on each call.

```
def make_counter():
    count = -1
    def _():
        count += 1
        return count
    return _

count_row = make_counter()
```

Now `count_row` will return a new value on each call:

```
>>> count_row()
0
>>> count_row()
1
```

This is sort of the dual of a class. You have a function that "wraps" some data (*closes* over the variable), instead of a piece of data with an associated method. The class version; note the similarity to `make_counter`:

```
class Count:
    def __init__(self):
        self.count = -1

    def __call__(self):
        self.count += 1
        return count
```

An instance of this class now behaves like our previous closure.

```
>>> count_row = Count()
>>> count_row()
0
>>> count_row()
1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a generator here that increments value by one every time it's called using `next()`:

```
def count_row():
    count = 0
    while True:
        count += 1
        yield count

itr = count_row()

print(next(itr))  # 1
print(next(itr))  # 2
```

If you look closely, this is equivalent to what [`itertools.count()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.count) does.

Answer (score -1):

if I got this right this should work:

```
count=0
def count_row(count): 
    count += 1 
    return count
```

Comment: I call the coun_row() later on and I get an error that states missing 1 required positional argument count

Comment: @nmhammer you shold call it like this ¨count_row(count)¨ and you probably called like this ¨count_row()¨